# Yaws Exception: {badmatch,{error,invalid_uri}} caused by +

Tags: exception, erlang, yaws

I cannot find out what's wrong with `abs_path` being "/search?search=Thrust+washers", and, what's more, how to debug this.

```
Class: error

Exception: {badmatch,{error,invalid_uri}}

Req: {http_request,'GET',{abs_path,"/search?search=Thrust+washers"},{1,1}}

Stack: [{myurl,pass_through,1,
               [{file,"/usr/local/lib/yaws/voxx/ebin/myurl.erl"},{line,507}]},

Line 506:
    Http_result = httpc:request(Url),
    {ok, {{V, S, R}, _, _}} = Http_result,
```

It seems to be caused by `+` (or `%20`) characters in Url, but these are perfectly legal.

I found [Yaws process died: {{badmatch,<<>>}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233897/yaws-process-died-badmatch) and the answer of Steve Vinoski, but cannot make use of it due to lack of experience.

Comment: Please include version information for Yaws and for Erlang/OTP.

Comment: Yaws 2.0.9 Erlang/OTP 24

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact nature of your application, but I'm guessing that what it's doing is that Yaws receives a request on a URL with a query containing the data you show, and then your code is attempting to use the Yaws-parsed URL to make a request as an HTTP client. I was able to duplicate your problem with this sort of setup.

I believe the '+' character in your query has to be URL-encoded because '+' is listed as reserved in the ["Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax" specification, Section 2.2 (RFC3986)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2); it is normally used to represent space characters in queries.

Using the Erlang functions in the [`uri_string` module](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/uri_string.html) to compose a query, we see that it gets encoded:

```erlang
1> uri_string:compose_query([{"search", "Thrust+washers"}]).
"search=Thrust%2Bwashers"
2> uri_string:dissect_query("search=Thrust%2Bwashers").
[{"search","Thrust+washers"}]
```

We see the same in Python:

```py
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode({'search': 'Thrust+washers'})
'search=Thrust%2Bwashers'
```

If you make a curl request to Yaws using a URL with the query encoded in this manner, Yaws decodes your query as `{"page","x+y"}` as you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Right on Spot! Very instructive. And sorry for the misspelling of your name.

Comment: uri_string:compose_query([{"search", "Thrust washers"}]). 
"search=Thrust+washers" So blank is transformed in +; urlencode does the trick